# Custom additional custom address attributes not getting saved

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, customer, backend

I have created two custom address attribute latitude and longitude in custom address and they are showing fine in backend. However when I am creating a new customer from backend filling some value to these new attributes, they are not getting saved to database.

Anyone please suggest

Comment: have you tried `bin/magento cache:flush` ? 
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-flush-enable-disable-cache.html

Comment: How did you create the address attributes?

Comment: I have created through installData. Please see the scripts 
$eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address','latitude',
   [
    'type'         => 'varchar',
    'label'        => 'Latitude',
    'input'        => 'text',
    'required'     => false,
    'visible'      => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'position'     => 999,
    'system'       => 0,
   ]
  );
  $latitudeAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'latitude');

Comment: Hi mrfizh, yes just tried after cache:flush, its not working

Comment: Is it Magento CE or Magento commerce ?

Comment: share your code of creating attribute into your question it self.